# JavaFX Collision Detection - Any tips?

Tags: java, javafx, collision-detection

I am currently making a small game for a school project and am having trouble with the collision detection.

Here is my timeline and jump button code:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
                    new KeyValue(player.translateYProperty(), ty, 
                    interpolator)),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(.5),
                    new KeyValue(player.translateYProperty(), ty-40, 
                    interpolator)));

Timeline eTimeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
                     new KeyValue(enemy.translateXProperty(), ex, 
                     interpolator2)),
                     new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(3),
                     new KeyValue(enemy.translateXProperty(), ex-40, 
                     interpolator2)));

JumpBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

            timeline.setCycleCount(2);
            timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
            JumpBtn.setDisable(true);
            setScore();
            timeline.setOnFinished(evt -> JumpBtn.setDisable(false));
            timeline.play();
        }
    });
```

And here is my attempt at the collision detection:

```
    double playX = player.getX();
    double enemX = enemy.getX();
    double playY = player.getY();
    double enemY = enemy.getY();
    boolean collisionX = false;
    boolean collisionY = false;

    if (playX == 450 && enemX == 450){
        collisionX = true;
        System.out.println("Collision X Detected");
    }
    if (enemY == 480 && playY == 420){
        collisionY = true;
        System.out.println("Collision Y Detected");
    }

    while (death = false){
        if (collisionX = true){
            if(collisionY = true){
                death = true;
                System.out.println("Player is dead");
            }
        }
    }
```

I can only assume this doesn't work because it isn't constantly looking for the X and Y position but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: `while (death = false){` Note that you are doing an assignment and not a comparison here. Also this will end in an endless loop if there was no collision.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if JavaFX has a

```
contains(Point point)
```

method, but if it does you should use that to detect a collision between two different shapes. 
Remember, two shapes/polygons are colliding if, at the least, one of the points which makes up the shape/polygon are touching and or inside another shape/polygon.

[ ==This is contained in the brackets, so its colliding==   ]